# Safely Creating "Heart Beat" over Network (Ping?)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, ping

I created extended TCP server and TCP client classes (in C#) for communication over network for my project use.

And as far as I understand, a client cannot really know if a server is down unless *it requests for something which expects a reply but does not get it*.

In our application, time and availability (of the server) are critical factors as it involve heavy machines for automation. Hence, according to the discussion on the design, **the server is supposed to send its "Heart Beat" periodically** such that in case a client does not receive anything from server after a period of time, it will:

1. Start to attempt its own recovery actions and if it still fails,
2. It will raise alarm to the service officer in the control room

I am supposed to implement the "heart beat" part in the server. And I have simple implementation of creating "Heart Beat".

```
public void SendHeartBeatToAllClients(byte[] hbdata) {
  foreach (Socket socket in clientNoSocketList.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())
    socket.Send(hbdata);      
}
```

So far it works fine, but one thing that worries me is that the heart beat data (`hbdata`) is short (only few pre-arranged bytes, to save time to talk over many machines) and self-defined and since the server also sends some other data besides the `hbdata`, and considering the possible latency or other unexpected case, there is always a possibility for this `hbdata` to be mixed up. Also, in my "heart beat" implementation, the client does not need reply anything to the server.

So here are my questions:

1. Is my worry not well-grounded (as it is fine so far)? Is there any flaw?
2. Is `Ping` a better or a common way to have such heart beat functionality over TCP? Why or why not?
3. If `Ping` is to be implemented, considering that `Ping` has reply, is there a way to implement replyless `Ping`?
4. Any suggestion to make the heart beat robust enough yet in the shortest amount of data possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is probably the hardest question to answer. Can you provide a little more detail? Why do you think that your server can't handle sending more than a few bytes?  Are we talking thousands of machines here?  Is everything on a local LAN, or does this go across multiple networks, or the internet?
2. `Ping` is an ICMP echo request - ping is very commonly used by networking monitor software, etc to ensure that clients are online.  Typically you do not need to implement your own, if you are just pinging for network access (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx).

   Also note that `ping` is not over TCP at all, but rather ICMP, a somewhat different protocol, used for network diagnostics among other things.  But that brings me to number 3...
3. `Ping` *without* a reply is kind of pointless.  For what you have in mind, I think the protocol you want is UDP - you can broadcast an arbitrary datagram, with no need for any kind of handshake or reply (TCP by definition involves establishing a session with a handshake) - it just sends. These would be Sockets with `SocketType.Dgram` instead of `SocketType.Stream`, and `ProtocolType.Udp` instead of Tcp or ICMP.  If you want to get a little more involved, you can use Broadcast to send to same thing to the entire LAN, or Multicast to send to a specific group of clients.
4. Again, are you sure you need to be that concerned about limiting traffic, etc here?

   Personally, I would flip it around, and have the clients "Check In" at a set interval, reporting a status code to the server.  If the server notices a client hasn't checked in for a while, it should send a message to the client and expect a reply.

   If you really are having issues scaling that up, I would have the server send the "Heart beats" via UDP at a set interval, and if the client thinks it's missing them, have a mechanism for it to hit the server and ask for a reply - and *then* if it doesn't get a response, raise the alarm.

Edit: just saw Prabhu's answer - he's right, `ping` will only tell you if the computer is up, you definitely want something inside the actual application to report back, not just the status of the network connection.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the Ping is ICMP rather than TCP and is necessary to have reply if we use it. Yes, the correct term for such one-way message sending is not "Ping" I believe. This is just my limited term. And I also consider the possibility of the clients sending messages actually, but unfortunately that was not (yet) in the design agreed.

Answer (score 1):

> > in my "heart beat" implementation, the client does not need reply anything to the server.

Application level keep-alives need to be two-way is'n't? What the above enables is that clients can be sure that server is alive and healthy on receiving the heart beat. If the client does not respond, server will not know the true status of the client. If client becomes unreachable,heart beats pile up in the servers send buffer. Server application will be oblivious to the fact.

> > Is my worry not well-grounded (as it is fine so far)? Is there any flaw?

Small sized bytes shouldn't be a problem. Its better the heart beats are small.

> > Is Ping a better or a common way to have such heart beat functionality over TCP? Why or why not?

Ping will be positive even if the client application is down but the system is healthy.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some insight. I understand that Ping is not good enough to see if the service is up and suggesting that best way to see keep-alives in the application level is two way communication. But size is not the real problem here.